# nopCommerce asp.net core performance

Tags: asp.net-core, nopcommerce, nopcommerce-4.1

I've done small performance test of last version of nopCommerce 4.10, results are not good. https://github.com/nopSolutions/nopCommerce/issues/3257

Is there anybody who already faced with the issue? Does anyone have ideas how to find and fix root cause?

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems (high memory usage) is solved by adding this code into your **Nop.Web.csproj** file:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>  
    <ServerGarbageCollection>false</ServerGarbageCollection>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Or just download the updated version of 4.10 with this change applied.

You can do more by running nopCommerce as a 32-bit application. You will need to install 2-bit version of .NET Core Runtime and changing the processPath attribute of the  element in your web.config file to the path of your 32-bit dotnet.exe (for us it was C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe) like this:

```xml
<aspNetCore requestTimeout="23:00:00" 
 processPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe" 
 arguments=".\Nop.Web.dll" 
 forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" 
 stdoutLogEnabled="false" 
 stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" 
 startupTimeLimit="3600" />
```

Note: You can download the 32-bit version of .NET Core Runtime from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/2.1).

Comment: I've tried those things before, it doesn't help a lot.

Comment: Any new information on this topic?  We are seeing the same issue.  Performance is great with a few users, but load testing with 20+ concurrent users results in 5+ second response times and goes up from there.  50 users results in 8-10 seconds.

Comment: There are lot's of performance issue but the main problem is about guest user and releated inserts with it like generic attribute records. You can try some settings like disabling ACL rules but  there are lots of thing to do. Generally the bottleneck is in sql side.